# Why is minor GC so frequent

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

This is my JVM parameters:

```
> /usr/local/java/bin/java -Xloggc:log/gc.log -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=64m -Xss128K -server -Xmn1024m -Xms3027m -Xmx3027m -Dresin.home=/usr/local/resin
```

I using Resin,the up is Resin start JVM parameters,the following is my GC output when I using jstat -gcutil pid 1000 1000

```
   S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   

  0.00   1.60  46.21  25.62  21.69  72639  941.082    31    0.275  941.357

  1.51   0.00  51.91  25.63  21.69  72640  941.093    31    0.275  941.368

  0.00   1.87  62.96  25.64  21.69  72641  941.104    31    0.275  941.379

  1.51   0.00  86.39  25.65  21.69  72642  941.114    31    0.275  941.389

  0.00   1.56  94.28  25.65  21.69  72643  941.126    31    0.275  941.401

  0.00   1.45   5.03  25.67  21.69  72645  941.146    31    0.275  941.421

  1.74   0.00  18.76  25.68  21.69  72646  941.158    31    0.275  941.433

  0.00   1.85  37.51  25.69  21.69  72647  941.169    31    0.275  941.443

  1.59   0.00  53.58  25.70  21.69  72648  941.180    31    0.275  941.455

  0.00   1.74  74.02  25.71  21.69  72649  941.192    31    0.275  941.467
```

We can find the minor GC about once per second,I feel it's very frequent,because my new Edanz size is 1g.so why so frequent or that's a normal thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either you Eden size is not 1 GB or you are creating an incredible about of garbage. As you don't appear to be setting your Eden size, suspects it much smaller than you think.

Try using `jstat -gccause` instead to see the sizes.

I suspect you have been reading http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/performance/jvm-tuning.xtp which incorrectly states that `-Xmn` sets the Eden space. ;)

The `-Xmx` option sets the maximum total heap size (young and old)

The `-Xmn` option sets the size of the young generation which consists of the Eden space and two survivor spaces.  As your survivor spaces don't appear to be very full, I suspect they account for most of the 1 G of young generation.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/exactoptions-jsp-141536.html

Try setting the `-XX:SurvivorRatio=` to something like 10 and most of the 1 GB will be Eden space.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Comment: Eden Space:
   capacity = 859045888 (819.25MB)

   used     = 656363136 (625.9566650390625MB)

   free     = 202682752 (193.2933349609375MB)

   76.4060622568279% used

From Space:

   capacity = 107347968 (102.375MB)

   used     = 1623640 (1.5484237670898438MB)

   free     = 105724328 (100.82657623291016MB)

   1.5125018481952075% used

To Space:

   capacity = 107347968 (102.375MB)

   used     = 0 (0.0MB)

   free     = 107347968 (102.375MB)

   0.0% used

Comment: In that case, you appear to be creating an insane amount of garbage. :| I would try using a memory profiler like VisualVM or YourKit.

Comment: Hi Peter,thanks your help,I pasted the Eden Space rang,minus from and to area it remain 600M,I think even 600M,it's should not get so frequent minor gc.
Is there any standars how many gc times are normal?
Thanks

Comment: You appear to be creating 600-800 MB of garbage per second. In that case, it would be normal to have such frequent minor GCs. I would see if you can reduce the garbage to 1-10 MB per second or less.

Comment: Dear Peter,Reduce garbage from 600M t0 10M,that's very difficult for me,do you have any good idea?
And if I extend new generation size to 2g,if more better?
Thanks

Comment: The good idea is to use a memory profiler like I said and find where the garbage is being created and change the code so it doesn't do it so much.  You can increase your Eden size to 8 GB, but the rate you are creating objects will be hurting performance significantly.

Comment: I am re-running a program which I haven't tuned in a while with `-verbosegc` After 100 mins of CPU and processing 58 GB of data its Eden space is 50% full, the survivor and old spaces are empty as it hasn't GCed once. You don't know what you can achieve until you try. ;)

Comment: Thanks peter,I will do that like you said.
But,If the code is very perfact(I said maybe :) ),so if we should extend the new generation size to reduce the minor gc times(I think so frequent gc may hurting performace and occupy more CPU) or we do nothing,because we think the gc times is very normal and good.
Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't be using words like `insane amount of garbage` or `use a memory profiler` if I thought it was very good. ;) Whether its a real problem is up to you to decide.  You could double the size of the eden space with not much penalty, but you have the overhead of **creating** objects to consider as well.

Comment: yes,I will optimize my code,but one thing you may don't know,my resin server deal about 2500 requests per second,so this is also one important reason.

Comment: I am sure that the library is a major cause, which will make it difficult to fix. Its worth checking that you really can't do anything about it.

Comment: @Jack Could you please share the issues on frequent minor GC? Is it still a problem if minor GC takes <1 sec? I can avoid it by increasing the Young Gen space. I would like to know the problems with frequent minor GC. I know one problems is Minor GC are also stop-the-world pauses.